# Check if ids exists in multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this problem where I need to ensure that some `ObjectId`s posted to my endpoint actually exist in their respective collections.

To do this I issue a simple count query across all the collections and check if `count > 0`:

```
db.collection.count({_id: {
          $in: objectIds
}))
```

However, this results in a new query for every collection. Is there any clever way of issuing a count (or another query) across multiple collections?

This is fine from a performance standpoint but I'm paying for every outbound request to my MongoDB server and I want to keep them to a minimum.

Another way to solve this is to create the object with the reference ids first, then run an aggregation on it and check for nulls:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { _id: newlyCreatedId }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "nameOfCollectionOne",
        localField: "collectionOneReference",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "collectionOneReference"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "nameOfCollectionTwo",
        localField: "collectionTwoReference",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "collectionTwoReference"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "nameOfCollectionThree",
        localField: "collectionThreeReference",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "collectionThreeReference"
      }
    }

])
```

And check:

```
if(!objectRetunedFromAggregation.collectionOneReference[0] || !objectRetunedFromAggregation.collectionTwoReference[0] || !objectRetunedFromAggregation.collectionThreeReference[0]){
  throw new Exception(...)
}
```

But this seems like a dirty solution, right?

Comment: I don't get exactly what's your issue? Are you looking for a cleaner way to do it or ... ?

Comment: @ZombieChowder yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

If you do this operation all the time, a "cleaner" solution may involve creating a new collection that centralizes the `_id` record, and on which collection those `_id` exists.

Of course, you would pay for this during insert time. However if your workload is a lot more read than writes, then the tradeoff may be worth it.

For example, you could have a `idRepo` collection, e.g.:

```
> db.idRepo.find()
{_id: 0, exists: ['coll_1', 'coll_2']}
{_id: 1, exists: ['coll_2']}
{_id: 2, exists: ['coll_3']}
....
```

where `_id` is the `_id` field you want to keep track of, and `exists` contains an array of collection names where the `_id` exists.

You would then need only a single query to find out what collection a certain `_id` exists in.

Note that you would need to do housekeeping on this `idRepo` collection yourself, and would need to insert/update the documents there to reflect the situation in the other collections.